# Setting file permissions when uploading with FTP protocol in WinSCP

Tags: file, permissions, ftp, winscp

When I upload a file through FTP using WinSCP to a server, it always sets the permission to `rw-------`.

I've tried changing the settings but the textboxes are blurred out.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

WinSCP does not support setting permissions automatically during upload with FTP protocol:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_transfer_custom#upload

You can change permissions explicitly after upload though:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_properties